# Android drawLine under view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas

In a canvas I draw some lines and place some images, the image is this (image 1)

[image]

But I'd like the lines under the images (image 2).

[image]

Here the XML for image

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/aw"
        />
```

Here the XML of the view

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/i3"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"/>

<view
            android:id="@+id/view"
            class="com.package.DrawCoord"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

in file `DrawCoord.kt`:

```
cv.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
cv.drawLine(....)
```

In `MainActvity.kt`:

```
val p=findViewById<View>(R.id.image1)
val x=findViewById<View>(R.id.i3)
x.setBackground(p.background)
```

How I can draw the lines under the image?

Comment: Hi, could you please add an image of what you exactly want, because, I didn't get your question clearly

Comment: Hi @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI I posted the images 1 and 2 in the first one the line goes inside the image, I'd like get the second image

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by changing the z-order of the views. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setZ(float)

```
x.setZ(10.0f);
```

should bring it to the front. Try different (positive or negative) values to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Views of the same elevation are drawn in the order you specify in your XML, from top to bottom. The view that you want to be drawn behind the other view should therefore come first in your XML.